# Error when Reading Multiple docx files inside a folder into multiple dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-docx

Sorry I had wrote a similar question elsewhere but I have forgotten its email Id hence writing back again.
I am trying to write a code where I have to read multiple docx files and extract a particular table from each of the docx file and create dataframes for each of them. my code goes like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
import os
directory = 'C:\\folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
     for document in files:
         if document.endswith('.docx'):
             table_num=4
             nheader=2
             table =document.tables[table_num-1]
             data=[[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for row in table.rows]
             df = pd.DataFrame(data)
             df='df_' + document
             outside_col,inside_col =df.iloc[0],df.iloc[1]
             hier_index =pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(outside_col,inside_col)))
             df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=hier_index).drop(df.index[[0,1]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I am getting the error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tables'

but I was able to run the same thing for single file as a function.

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
import os
directory = 'C:\\folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4'

def read_docx_table(document,table_num=1,nheader=1):
    table =document.tables[table_num-1]
    data=[[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for row in table.rows]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    if nheader ==1:
        df=df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
    elif nheader == 2:
        outside_col,inside_col =df.iloc[0],df.iloc[1]
        hier_index =pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(outside_col,inside_col)))
        df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=hier_index).drop(df.index[[0,1]]).reset_index(drop=True)
    elif nheader>2:
        print("Not Working")
        df.DataFrame()
    return df


document = Document("file1.docx")
table_num=2
nheader=0
df = read_docx_table(document,table_num,nheader)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

got help and changed accordingly
problem was document was a string before now its a document object

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
import os
directory = 'path'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
     for document in files:
         if document.endswith('.docx'):
             table_num=4
             nheader=2
             joined_path = os.path.join(directory,document)
             document1 = Document(joined_path)
             table =document1.tables[table_num-1]
             data=[[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for row in table.rows]
             df = pd.DataFrame(data)
             outside_col,inside_col =df.iloc[0],df.iloc[1]
             hier_index =pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(outside_col,inside_col)))
             df1=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=hier_index).drop(df.index[[0,1]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).